# Function or operator for matrix exponential in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

I am looking for a function or operator
that computes the n-th matrix exponential in Julia
where n is a non-negative integer.
For example, in MATLAB I would write `expm(A, 3)` for `A * A * A`.
I could just call the product using `*` multiple times,
but is there a way to compute the matrix exponential
without doing this?

```
julia> A = [1 -1; 0 2]
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  -1
 0   2

julia> A * A
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  -3
 0   4

julia> A * A * A
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  -7
 0   8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the exponentiation operator.

```
julia> A = [1 -1; 0 2]
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  -1
 0   2

julia> A^2
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  -3
 0   4

julia> A^3
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  -7
 0   8
```

To find out where it's implemented, you can use the function **methods**

```
julia> methods(^)
# 45 methods for generic function "^":
...

^(A::Array{T,2}, p::Integer) at linalg/dense.jl:170
^(x, p::Integer) at intfuncs.jl:108
^(A::Array{T,2}, p::Number) at linalg/dense.jl:173
```

Given that information, you can find it in [the Julia repository](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/linalg/dense.jl#L172).